# Rcpp map/dictionary/list

Tags: c++, r, dictionary, rcpp

How do I pass in a map/dictionary/list from R as a parameter to a c++ function?

For example, I want to do something like the following:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test(List map) {
    int val = map["test"];
    return(val);
}

/*** R
map <- list(test = 200, hello = "a")
test(map)
*/
```

where the output should be 200.

Comment: I just tried your code as is, using `sourceCpp` and I got 200. What is your `sessionInfo` ?

Comment: R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] foreach_1.4.1   fpc_2.1-5       flexmix_2.3-10  lattice_0.20-15 mclust_4.1      cluster_1.14.4 
[7] MASS_7.3-26     Rcpp_0.10.3    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8   grid_3.0.1        iterators_1.0.6   modeltools_0.2-19 stats4_3.0.1     
[6] tools_3.0.1

Comment: I use linux not mac and don't know if it is related. But in my setup I have `packageVersion("Rcpp") == ‘0.10.4’`. Try to uprgade Rcpp from r-forge and run the code again.

Comment: =/ Tried on linux and upgraded Rcpp. http://imgur.com/dUne9NY

Comment: Wow really difficult. Try this : `Rscript --vanilla -e "require(Rcpp, lib.loc = 'your_libray_path');sourceCpp('test.cpp')"`

Comment: Still not working =/ but I did figure out that for some reason, if the list contains vectors, everything works fine. ex. map = list(test = c(1, 2, 3)) works fine. I guess for now I will make everything a vector

Comment: I have a similar problem on Mac OSX. Running the code above seems to always return 1.

Comment: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html under "Lists and data frames"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem on Mac OS X. Running your snippet seems to always return `1`. However, if I modify the code in the following way it works:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test(List map) {
    int val = as<int>( map["test"] );
    return(val);
}

/*** R
map <- list(test = 200, hello = "a")
test(map)
*/
```

It seems like something is going wrong with the type inference -- the compiler should "know" that, since we're assigning `map["test"]` to an `int`-declared variable that it should be converted as `int`, but this does not seem to be the case. So, to be safe -- be sure to `as` anything that's coming out of an R list.

Also, it's worth stating: in R `200` is a `double`; if you want to explicitly pass an `int` you should write `200L`.

FWIW, I'm compiling with `clang++`:

```
> clang++ -v
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

and

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_0.10.4
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

May be I don't fully understand what you really want but if you want to pass an R list as a parameter to Cpp function it's possible

**Cpp code**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test(List map) {
    int number = 10;    
    int val = map["test"] + number;
    return(val);
}

/*** R
map <- list(test = 2, hello = "a")
test(map)
*/
```

Suppose that you saved this Cpp code  at "/tmp/test.cpp"

**R code**

```
require(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("/tmp/test.cpp")
test(map)
## [1] 12
```

Comment: that is what I wanted, but it doesn't work (I get the output to be 11 no matter what I put for number)

Comment: @tsuyoihikari  Without your code is difficult to tell. Did you try my example exactly as written ?

Comment: also above I was wrong, its not the number that's the problem, its the map. no matter what I put for test (ex. test = 2, test = 5, etc.) I get output=11, so it is treating map["test"] as 1 no matter what

Comment: @tsuyoihikari Thanks I forgot to add #include Rcpp.h. But I still don't get why it doesn't work. Can you edit your question and add your code I'll test it on my linux box